# Div not scrollable when main viewport is scrollable

Tags: html, css

I made a three column layout for my web app where the two left columns form the menu and submenu and the third column is the main viewport. However, the second column (div) isn't scollable when the main viewport is scrollable even though it does show a scroll bar. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="container">

<div id="top" class="clearfix">
    Header
</div>

<div id="container_menu">
    <ul id="menu">
        <li>Menu goes here</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="container_submenu">
    <div id="submenu">
    Submenu goes here
        <strong>WHY WON'T THIS DIV SCROLL? (It is showing a scroll bar...)</strong><br />
        FILLER<br />
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main">
    FILLER<br />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after {
    content:"";
    display:table;
}
.clearfix:after {
    clear:both;
}
.clearfix {
    zoom:1;
    /* For IE 6/7 (trigger hasLayout) */
}
body, td, th {
}
body {
    background: #fff;
}
div#container {
    min-width: 800px;
    /*TODO*/
    width: 100%;
}
div#top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}
/* MENU */
 div#container_menu {
    background: #666;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 180px;
    margin-right: -180px;
    height: 100%;
}
ul#menu {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
/* SUBMENU */
 div#container_submenu {
    z-index: -1;
    background: #ebeef5;
    color: #999;
    position: fixed;
    left: 180px;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-right: -250px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}
div#submenu {
    margin-top: 50px;
}
div#main {
    margin-left:430px;
    margin-top: 50px;
}
```

[JS Fiddle with CSS](http://jsfiddle.net/radioactiverambo/cqr614oj/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `z-index` on `div#container_submenu` is -1. The div is being put under the `#container` div (which is transparent) so you can see the `#container_submenu` div, but not actually target it. Make the z-index of `div#container_submenu` 0 and it will fix it.

Comment: Thank you. That fixed it. I did have to use the z-index to make some animation stuff work (submenu should be behind menu and scroll out from underneath it), but giving it a higher z-index than the container solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

It's occluded by the `#main` div. Just remove `z-index: -1`. http://jsfiddle.net/zephod/4xp2jj3a/

Comment: Thank you too. This was indeed the solution to my problem.